# Cocos2d iOS: How to draw shadows underneath a CCNode

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm building a simple card game and would like to draw shadows when users pick the cards up. Any quick solutions?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution? Draw a black shape (or whatever the shadow color is) on a layer behind your selected card. Just like in your example image you have a fuzzy gray square box behind, but yet slightly down and to the right, of another square that is on a layer on top of it. Or you can draw the shape underneath the card and move the card a little to give the illusion of it rising.